# Actionscript 3 setting multiple variables of an object in an array possible?

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, set

Right now, I have many `MovieClips`'s in my array. I want to update all the `alpha` values of the MovieClips in my array.

Right now, I am using a for loop but this is not the fastest way to do it.

Is there a way to set values for all the items in my array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `ActionScript` doesn't have any constructs that allow you to change properties of all elements of the array with a single line of code. There is an [`Array.forEach()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Array.html#forEach()) method, but I think that would be slower than a simple `for(i = 0; i < len; i++)` loop as there is an overhead of calling a function for each item of the array.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to iterate through all the `MovieClip`s anyway, even if there was a language structure for ease of typing.

Answer (score 2):

```
for each(var m:MovieClip in myArray) {
    m.alpha = 0.3;
}
```

a for loop isn't bad.