# Can I target multiple objects with a single operation using ECMAScript's `with` statement?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, with-statement, ecma262

The following doesn't work (although it gives no explicit error), but **why** not?

And... Is there *really no way* around it, strictly using the *[with statement](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-12.10)*? Forget [using for / foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130569/actionscript-3-setting-multiple-variables-of-an-object-in-an-array-possible).

```
with (object1, object2) {
  attribute = value;
  method();
}
```

**edit:** Sorry to make 2 questions in 1. I'll try to make it clearer:

1. Why the code above gives no syntax error, doesn't work but is accepted by `with`?
2. If it's possible, how could we change multiple objects with same attribute using `with`?

Hopefully the following example will be more clear on what I wanted to accomplish:

```
var object1 = { attribute: 3 };
var object2 = { attribute: 2, method: function() { alert('blah'); } };
var object3 = { method: function() {alert('bleh'); } };

var value = 4;

with (object1) 
with (object2) 
with (object3) 
{
  attribute = value;
  method();
}

alert(object1.attribute + object2.attribute);

// resulting alerts should be, in order: blah, bleh, 8
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Introducing multi-object scope with `with`

This is what I *originally* thought you were after, since you hadn't specified what your expected results were. Just stack the `with` statements:

```
var object1 = { attribute: 3 };
var object2 = { method: function() { alert('blah'); } };

var value = 4;

with (object1) 
with (object2) 
{
  attribute = value;
  method();
}

alert(object1.attribute);
```

Naturally, the object introduced by the inner-most `with` will override identically-named properties in any outer scope, including those of the outer `with` statements.

Standard disclaimers apply regarding performance hits and potential for errors caused by the use of `with`. Note that your example shows property access prefixed by `.` within the block, but this is incorrect - `with` modifies scope, temporarily putting an object at the front of the resolution chain, so no prefix is necessary (or allowed).

---

### Targeting multiple objects

Regarding your edit: the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Comma_Operator) lets you write something that *appears* to pass multiple expressions to `with`, but really only passes one of them.  You're not going to be able to accomplish what you want without some sort of multicast delegate implementation (one that involves looping); JavaScript/ECMAScript don't have any built-in means of modifying multiple properties / calling multiple methods with a single assignment / call.

#### Quick 'n' dirty implementation:

```
function multicast()
{
  this.targets = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
}
multicast.prototype = {
  call: function(methodName)
  {
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<this.targets.length; ++i)
    {
      if ( this.targets[i][methodName] )
        this.targets[i][methodName].apply(this.targets[i],
          Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    }
  },
  set: function(propName, value)
  {
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<this.targets.length; ++i) 
      this.targets[i][propName] = value;
  }
};
```

#### Usage:

```
var object1 = { attribute: 3 };
var object2 = { attribute: 2, method: function() { alert('blah'); } };
var object3 = { method: function() {alert('bleh'); } };

var value = 4;

var delegate = new multicast(object1, object2, object3);
delegate.set('attribute', value);
delegate.call('method');

alert(object1.attribute + object2.attribute);
```

Comment: That's pretty cool, but not it mostly makes me rephrase my question to what I originally meant... Please, try reading it again now! ;)

Comment: @Cawas: Hmm... The value of a good example that *specifies expected outputs* is proven yet again. I'm afraid you're in for some disappointment though - see my edit. You could probably come up with something a lot more clever using ECMAScript 5's getters/setters and a bit of pre-processing to generate method stubs, but the fundamental behavior will be the same.

Comment: That's perfect, Shog, thanks! Now I'm just wondering yet 2 more things: (1) Does ActionScript have such built-in means? Probably not, as well. (2) Were [ECMAscript a real dialect of LISP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030285/is-ecmascript-really-a-dialect-of-lisp), could we make your implementation to replace `with`'s original built-in function?

Comment: @Cawas: I'm not aware of anything, but I don't work with ActionScript either. However, I rather doubt it - it would be a rather large extension to ECMAScript for something that can be trivially implemented in a library.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a reference to the object if you want to make your code shorter:

```
var o1 = object1
,   o2 = object2
;
o1.attribute = value;
o2.method();
```

Comment: Also cool, but not trying to make code shorter - just wondering about an alternate syntax statement. ;)